# Send data to my mobile game users remotely

Tags: ios, json, rest, firebase

I'am developing a Mobile game and i would like to send my users new levels (JSON files) every month. What is the best way to do that (FireBase, REST API, ...). Could someone help me to choose the best practices used in games ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's independent from game design or not.

You'll first have to think if you want to *actively* send the levels (using remote notifications), or if the app will check each and every month some web service if new data is available. In any case, the arbitrary "level" data has to be downloaded actively by the app.

Which technique you use depends on your own preferences. Maybe you should also think of some cloud storage like Amazon S3, this might scale better than an own-hosted solution if you expect high loads at the beginning of a month or so. This will narrow down your choices.

Transferring the data might also depend on the size to be transferred. I would almost always try to compress the data, and unzip it at the client site.

***Update***

You could also think of initially assigning each client a random day for downloading level data (only use day 1-28, not 1-31, or you might get problems with too-short-months), e.g. client 1 might download each 5th of a month, client 2 each 2nd, client 3 each 14th and so on. This will reduce the download peak to about 3%, because every day only 1/28 of your clients downloads new levels.

Comment: Since i'am using FireBase as backend. The fact that users download levels every month may generate an access peak in FireBase. 
Here are the steps that i'am doing right now :
1- Ask for new version if last connection Month != current Month  
2- If there is a new version, download file from Firebase Storage
3- Save data locally in the sandbox of the user

Comment: See my update regarding the download peaks